# Xcode 5, storyboard update image position issues

Tags: interface-builder, storyboard, xcode5

When I open up my Xcode 4.x project in Xcode 5 and load a Storyboard some strange things are occurring. Mainly, some of my images are getting re-sized and positioned. The size always gets set to 0,0 and the position is somewhere WAY off screen. Values like -3007,12824. This is an app with a massive amount of storyboard layout and while it hasn't messed with all the images, there are easily 500+ that have this problem.

for example this

`<rect key="frame" x="403" y="134" width="572" height="486"/>`

changed to

`<rect key="frame" x="-815" y="1490" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>`

I've tried setting the storyboard to Xcode 4.6 version, but no effect. Anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it (short of manually discarding all the changes I don't want)?

edit: I am using the GM Seed for Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/891663#891663) on the Apple Developer forums which seems to imply this is a bug. I've submitted the appropriate radars to Apple to help the find the root cause (as they've suggested).

In the meantime, I have a simple process for converting my storyboard.

1. Open them in Xcode 5.
2. Say I want to commit the changes (we all use source control, right?)
3. Select each storyboard in the list of modified files, go down the XML diffs and discard any changes which move my images. They are fairly easy to spot.
4. Add a comment and finish the commit.

After the initial conversion, from 4.x -> 5, Xcode screwed with the location of my images. While it's an annoying process, it's a lot quicker than either re-creating the storyboard or manually trying to move items back to their original position.

Oh yeah... and please file Radars with Apple so they can solve the issue. :)

Comment: What to do if no source control? I just tried replacing the XCode 4.6 compatible storyboard (alas, I had backup) while it was open in XCode 5 and it screwed it again!!

Comment: Never code without source control. At bare minimum just check off box to have Xcode create a local GIT repository on project creation, then get into the habit of committing. You might be able to accomplish the same thing using a diff program and a backup/snapshop. FileMerge is an app which can do it and conveniently it's Xcode (as in show file contents) then in the Applications folder.

Comment: Source control is highly recommended but you can archive project other ways. My suggestion is easy. ZIP project periodically and do compare different versions. In Beyond Compare you can easily compare and modify at least as you can in SC view.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well for some storyboards when I switched between iOS 6 view and iOS 7 view.  Only workaround that I have found was to recreate the storyboard from scratch (using XCode 5.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after loading an existing Storyboard into Xcode 5, it got automatically updated to the new format, and all the image views were missing.

Turns out the view hierarchies were intact, only the frames were messed up. I went through and fixed all the image view frames, and that fixed the project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found that swapping NSBoxes for NSView fix it and let its contents rest in peace, but...

I have a NSTableCellView with a NSTextField. I set the NSTextField position, clean and build and I do can see my NSTextField in its position. But, if instead of building while I have this NSWindow ON the screen, I build the project while displaying another NSWindow the position of the NSTextField is modified to strange values. Uffff, I don't know what to do next. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!! With XCode 5, if  you hide a NSTableColumn and try to modify de NSTableCellView's width, you'll find that x=-0 (?) and width=0. No matter how hard you try to change it. It won´t work. The only way to set the x position and width is to unhide the NSTableColumn, adjust de x and width and then hide it again. It took me a while to get across the solution. I hope that Apple makes something about it.